# running code for a different sheet than I'm on

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone advise what's wrong with this code?  I'm trying to delete any row that is blank or has the word "Pending" in column 8.

This code works if the "Modifications" sheet is active, but not if I try to run it from another worksheet.  Ideally I'd like it to run without actually activating or selecting the sheet.  Is that possible?

Thanks!

```
Sub pending_blank_delete()

With Sheets("Modifications")
  last_mod_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(last_mod_row, 8))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.find("Pending", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(last_mod_row, 8)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify the references to `Range` and `Cells` to start.  You could always just pass a string parameter for "Modifications" or an actual Worksheet reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you...

Your range didn't specify which sheet so I moved everything inside the With statement. When you see `Set SrchRng = Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(last_mod_row, 8))`, the `.Cells(2, 8)` means `Sheets("Modifications").Cells(2, 8)`.  Without placing it inside the `With` statement, it's going to create the range from the active sheet.  An alternative without using the `With` statement would be `Set SrchRng = Range(Sheets("Modifications").Cells(2, 8), Sheets("Modifications").Cells(last_mod_row, 8))`.

```
Sub pending_blank_delete()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng

With Sheets("Modifications")
    last_mod_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SrchRng = Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(last_mod_row, 8))

    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Pending", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

    On Error Resume Next

    Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(last_mod_row, 8)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @tjb1, this is perfect.  Could you tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Updated answer with more.